# AuthenticationBuilder does not contain a definition for "AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp"

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, asp.net-core-5.0

In the startup.cs file, I tried the following lines to connect the Azure AD B2C into my .Net Core 5 Web-API project followed from a GitHub Repo [Here](https://github.com/aksoftware98/aadb2c-app). But it's not accepting the AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp predefined method in my .Net Core 5+ React template project. Where did I go wrong?

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
```

I have tried with OpenId scheme and the following method as well.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAdB2C"));
```

Comment: Have you got the `Microsoft.Identity.Web` package installed? Have you got `using Microsoft.Identity.Web;` in the code file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't installed the below-given package!.

```
Microsoft.Identity.Web;
```

Comment: be sure to import the library ' using Microsoft.Identity.Web; ' as per suggested by DaviG